# Issue with timezone in oracle

Tags: oracle, timezone

Below query is used in my code to get the timezone from database. (DB is in central time zone)

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
-05:00
```

When daylight saving is on (CDT), its expected result.

but when daylight saving ends (CST), my result should be GMT-06, but i am still getting GMT-05.

Googled and got below options :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR') FROM dual;

SELECT TZ_OFFSET('CST6CDT') FROM DUAL;
```

Will above queries run correctly accordingly to CST and CDT ??

Comment: How *exactly* have you configured the DB to be in the Central time zone? And what does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBTIMEZONE` **does not** determine the time zone of `SYSTIMESTAMP` (or `SYSDATE`)

Time zone of `SYSTIMESTAMP` is the time zone of database server's operating system.

`DBTIMEZONE` is only relevant for data type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` and defines the time zone in which those values are stored internaly. You cannot change `DBTIMEZONE` on your database if the database contains a table with a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column and the column contains data.